# SQL Server Full Text Search on Numeric values

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search

I know the full text search doesn't work on numeric data type fields, but I'd like to include the numeric values in my search.

I've got a list of Items, and there are 3 columns in the Items table that are of data type numeric.  However, this table is not the one I have my full text search catalog applied to. I have another table, FTSItems that I'm searching (Items actually exists in another database).

So, I'm considering converting all numeric values to text (nvarchar) in my table that the Full Text Search will be applied towards.

NOTE: The original Items table comes from a Microsoft Dynamics database.  This table will sometimes take these numeric values and plug them into the Item tables 'ItemName' column.

For example:

```
 ItemID:       1
 ItemName:     Bottlecap .25 inch diameter blue
 OrificeSize:  .25  (Datatype numeric(6,2) considering converting to nvarchar)
 Color:        blue
```

I just want to know if this is a worthwhile approach to take, or if there is another possible solution to my search requirements.

**UPDATE**

I should have included this in my original question. I'm trying to give the users a google like search, where the user only has a single textbox. The search then will need to search for the users input on all columns on the table.

I've borrowed some of the ideas presented in [this article](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Full-Text+Search+%282008%29/64248/).

Comment: It's not clear why you want to do this. Why not query the numeric column directly using a numeric parameter? Can you show a sample query and explain why you can't use a 'normal' query?

Answer (score 1):

Your approach sounds reasonable.

I haven't tried it, but I wonder if you might be able to use a computed column, rather than having to set up triggers or some other mechanism to convert the numbers to a string.

Also, keep in mind that you can combine multiple columns into a single fulltext index, to allow searching all of them with a single query.

Comment: I may do that (add the numeric values to the fulltext index). Thanks.